# How to match EMGU CV SIFT keypoints of two images?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want code to match two pictures on basis of SIFT keypoints.?

I have the following code for SIFT

```
public static Image<Bgr, Byte> siftFunction(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> modelImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(sourceBitmap);
        SIFTDetector siftCPU = new SIFTDetector();
        VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
        MKeyPoint[] mKeyPoints = siftCPU.DetectKeyPoints(modelImage, null);
        modelKeyPoints.Push(mKeyPoints);
        ImageFeature<float>[] reulst = siftCPU.ComputeDescriptors(modelImage, null, mKeyPoints);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> result = Features2DToolbox.DrawKeypoints(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, new Bgr(Color.Red), Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.DEFAULT);
        return result;
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use the provided example of object detection and then compare the area of detection. In case the whole observed image corresponds to the model image - your images match.

other solution - do not use the descriptors at all but just select the key points. Then compare the key points arrays of the two pictures and in case of equality consider the images to be matching.

first solution is somehow more reliable while the second is faster and easier.